# How to break a dictionary into a list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a dictionary into a list, which contains many dictionaries. for example:

input:

```py
{
    'first-name':'foo',
    'last-name':'bar',
    'gender':'unknown',
    'age':99
}
```

output:

```py
[{'first-name': 'foo'}, {'last-name': 'bar'}, {'gender': 'unknown'}, {'age':99}]
```

I am already using this code to do such:

```py
def convert(info: dict):
    new_list = list

    for item in info:
        new_parameter = {item:info[item]}
        new_list.append(new_parameter)

    return new_list
```

but I was wondering if there is a built-in function to do this? or a more readable piece of code? it's almost 10 lines! and kind of confusing to understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dict = {
    'first-name':'foo',
    'last-name':'bar',
    'gender':'unknown',
    'age':99
}
list = [(key, value) for key, value in Dict.items()]

list >> [('first-name':'foo'), ('last-name':'bar'), ('gender':'unknown'),('age':99)]
```

This is the simplest way to `Convert dictionary to list of tuples`

Reference : [Python | Convert dictionary to list of tuples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-dictionary-to-list-of-tuples/)

Answer (score 6):

Using list comprehension

- `items()` method is used to return the list with all dictionary keys with values.

**Ex.**

```
dict1 = {
    'first-name':'foo',
    'last-name':'bar',
    'gender':'unknown',
    'age':99
}

new_list = [{k:v} for k,v in dict1.items() ]
print(new_list)
```

**O/P:**

```
[{'first-name': 'foo'}, {'last-name': 'bar'}, {'gender': 'unknown'}, {'age': 99}]
```

Another solution suggested by @josoler

```
new_list = list(map(dict, zip(dict1.items())))
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you could also use: `list(map(dict, zip(dd.items())))`. Not the best choice for readability, though

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> d={
...     'first-name':'foo',
...     'last-name':'bar',
...     'gender':'unknown',
...     'age':99
... }
>>> [{k: v} for (k, v) in d.items()]
[{'first-name': 'foo'}, {'last-name': 'bar'}, {'gender': 'unknown'}, {'age': 99}]
```

Comment: why the negative vote on this, it solves the problem and is no wrong way, he need to edit code though

Comment: @prashantrana Could it be because it's exactly the same as bharatk's answer?

Comment: @Selcuk cant say on this, doesn't know the intention, yes this solution is like bharatk answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method:

```
>>> [dict([i]) for i in d.items()]
[{'gender': 'unknown'}, {'age': 99}, {'first-name': 'foo'}, {'last-name': 'bar'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
k={
    'first-name':'foo',
    'last-name':'bar',
    'gender':'unknown',
    'age':99
}

s =list(map(lambda x:{x[0]:x[1]},k.items() ))
```

output

```
[{'first-name': 'foo'},
 {'last-name': 'bar'},
 {'gender': 'unknown'},
 {'age': 99}]
```